# How to generate a sequential character vector without a loop?

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a character vector that includes a sequence of n numbers (as character) with m empty string elements in between each number element.

I managed to generate the vector using a loop. Is there a way to implement this more conciseley without a loop, and would this be more efficient?

```r
sequence = character(0)
n = 3
m = 2

for(i in 1:n){
  sequence <- c(sequence, rep("",m), i)
  i <- i + 1
}
```

The output is a vector like:

```r
c("","","1","","","2","","","3")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another way to with `rep` and `lapply`.

```
seq_fun <- function(n, m){
  unlist(lapply(1:n, function(x) c(rep("", times = m), x)))
}

seq_fun(3, 2)
# [1] ""  ""  "1" ""  ""  "2" ""  ""  "3"
```

Answer (score 4):

**1)** Create an m by n matrix of "" and rbind 1:n to the bottom of it.  Then unravel that into a vector:

```
c(rbind(matrix("", m, n), 1:n))
## [1] ""  ""  "1" ""  ""  "2" ""  ""  "3"
```

**2)** Another approach is to create an m1*n long vector of "" and replace positions m1*(1:n) with 1:n.

```
m1 <- m + 1
replace(character(m1 * n), m1 * (1:n), 1:n)
## [1] ""  ""  "1" ""  ""  "2" ""  ""  "3"
```

Alternately we could use a logical second argument:

```
replace(character(m1 * n), c(logical(m), TRUE), 1:n)
## [1] ""  ""  "1" ""  ""  "2" ""  ""  "3"
```

Answer (score 3):

**1)** We can use `lapply` to create the `vector`

```
unlist(lapply(1:3, function(x) c("", "", x)))
#[1] ""  ""  "1" ""  ""  "2" ""  ""  "3"
```

---

**2)** Or with `rep`

```
replace(rep("", 9), c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), 1:3)
#[1] ""  ""  "1" ""  ""  "2" ""  ""  "3"
```

---

**3)** Or using `rep` with `seq`

```
v1 <- rep("", 9)
v1[seq(3, length(v1), by = 3)] <- 1:3
```

---

**4)** Or using `paste` and `strsplit`

```
unlist(strsplit(sprintf("  %d", 1:3), " "))
#[1] ""  ""  "1" ""  ""  "2" ""  ""  "3"
```

NO Packages used

Answer (score 0):

A succinct way:

```r
library(purrr)

map2(1:3, 2, ~ c(rep("", .y), .x)) %>% unlist()
#> [1] ""  ""  "1" ""  ""  "2" ""  ""  "3"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>