# How to add coordinate-like labels alongside facet plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add coordinate-like labels to a faceted ggplot. My approach is not optimal because the position of the labels depend on the output size of the plot, and labels overlap with titles (I could of course add a line break to the subtitle). So it is quite cumbersome to set the right label position. Is there any better way to add these labels, possibly using some grob/grid functions?

The plot is faceted by the segment and scenario variables. My first idea was to add the coordinates using a text geom, however, this would add to many labels (one for each facet). So, I made vectors in which only the outer facets have content,

```r
c("","","1","","","2")
c("A","B","C","","","")
```

, also using a function from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56651857/7648774). I then set the position using the x and y argument, and set coord_fixed so that it's visible.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~segment, ~scenario, ~segment_coord, ~scenario_coord,~x,~y,
  "Segment A","Scenario 1","A","1", 1,1,
  "Segment B","Scenario 1","B","1", 2,2,
  "Segment C","Scenario 1","C","1", 4,4,

  "Segment A","Scenario 2","A","2", 1,1,
  "Segment B","Scenario 2","B","2", 2,2,
  "Segment C","Scenario 2","C","2", 4,4
)

make_plot2 <- function(df, my_scenarios, my_segments){

  # Prepare coordinate vectors
  n_rows <- length(my_scenarios)
  n_cols <- length(my_segments)

  seq_fun2 <- function(vector, empty_elements){
    unlist(lapply(vector, function(x) c(rep("", times = empty_elements), x)))
  }
  row_coordinates <- seq_fun2(my_scenarios, n_cols-1) # makes ["","","1","","","2"]
  col_coordinates <- c(my_segments, rep("", n_cols * (n_rows-1))) # makes ["A","B","C","","",""]

  df %>%
    filter(scenario_coord %in% my_scenarios) %>% 
    filter(segment_coord %in% my_segments) %>%  

    ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
      facet_grid(scenario ~ segment) +

      # geom_text(aes(label = segment_coord), x = 2.5, y = 5) + #  would add to many coordinate labels
      # geom_text(aes(label = scenario_coord), x = 5, y = 2.5) +  #  would add to many coordinate labels
      annotate("text", x = 5, y = 2.5, label = row_coordinates) + # adds row coordinates
      annotate("text", x = 2.5, y = 5, label = col_coordinates) + # adds column coordinates

      labs(subtitle = "Quite long subtitle that gets in the way", title = "Title") +
      theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,0.5,0.5),"cm")) +
      coord_fixed(xlim = c(1, 4), ylim = c(1, 4), clip = "off") # removes clipping, so that text is visible outside facets
}
```

Using different output sizes:

```r
make_plot2(df, c("1","2"), c("A","B","C"))

make_plot2(df, c("1","2"), c("A","B","C"))
```

Larger plot:

[image: Larger plot]

Smaller plot with shifted labels:

[image: Smaller plot]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a possible solution:

```r
my_scenarios <- c("1","2")
my_segments <- c("A","B","C")

plot <- df %>%
  filter(scenario_coord %in% my_scenarios) %>% 
  filter(segment_coord %in% my_segments) %>%  

  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
    facet_grid(scenario ~ segment) +
    labs(subtitle = "Quite long subtitle that gets in the way",
      title = "Title")
```

The plot is now much simpler. The next steps involve

- converting the *ggplot2 object* to a *ggplot2 plot grob*
- adding new grobs on top of the unused top and right axis (axis-t, axis-r),
- changing the height and width of the corresponding cells

```r
# Convert the plot to a grob
gt = ggplotGrob(plot)

add_coordinates <- function(gt, axis_name, labels){

  axis <- gt$layout %>% filter(str_detect(name, !!axis_name))
  for(i in 1:nrow(axis)) {
    axis_i <- slice(axis, i)

    # Construct label grobs and add to gtable
    new_grob_name <- paste("coordinate",i,sep = "-")
    gt <- gtable_add_grob(
      gt, 
      textGrob(labels[i], gp = gpar(fontsize = 8)), 
      t = axis_i$t, 
      l = axis_i$l, 
      b = axis_i$b, 
      r = axis_i$r, 
      z = axis_i$z + 1, # on top of axis 
      name = new_grob_name)
  }
  return(gt)
}

gt <- add_coordinates(gt, "axis-t", my_segments)
gt <- add_coordinates(gt, "axis-r", my_scenarios)

# Change the widths and heights. Set same size as strips
# TODO: make dynamic 
gt$heights[6] = unit(gt$heights[7], "cm") 
gt$widths[11] = unit(gt$widths[10], "cm") 

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

This solutions avoids messing up the layout, however, the top and right axes can't be used anymore.

[image: Final plot]